# Dereference of a possible null reference C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a C# method which throws the following warning on line `await _socketClient.Start();`:

> CS8602:   Dereference of a possibly null reference.

Method:

```
public async Task Connect()
{
    if ((_socketClient == null) || (_socketClient != null && _socketClient.IsRunning))
        return;

    await _socketClient.Start();
}
```

I am not able to understand why the compiler is giving that warning even though I have made an explicit null check the line above it and returning back to the caller method?

Interestingly, if I simplify the method to do a plain simple null reference check, the warning goes away.

Modified Method (No warning):

```
public async Task Connect()
{
    if (_socketClient == null)
        return;

    await _socketClient.Start();
 }
```

However, I need the additional check as well and not sure what is the mistake I am doing over there for the warning to pop up.

Environment:

- .Net 6.0 aspnet core application
- Visual Studio 2022 IDE

Comment: FYI, If you've already written `(_socketClient == null) ||` then whatever is after the `||` will only be evaluated when have a non-null `_socketClient` so it's redundant to then check `_socketClient != null` on the right side of the `||`.  e.g.:  `_socketClient == null || _socketClient.IsRunning` is the same logical check.

Comment: Is `IsRunning` a property?  If it executes arbitrary code, then it could potentially have a reference to the object and change the value of `_socketClient`.

Comment: IsRunning is a simple boolean property.

Comment: Wow, actually `if (_socketClient == null || _socketClient.IsRunning) return;` does not throw the warning. Looks like the redundant check of checking for not equal to null is causing the issue. Crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio only throws CS8602 when it detects the presence of "maybe-null".

Looks like you have it pretty much narrowed down, does refactoring it like below help at all?

```
public async Task Connect()
{
    if ( _socketClient == null ) {
        return;
    } else if ( _socketClient.IsRunning ) {
        return;
    } else {
        await _socketClient.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The simplified version also works. Just that I had to take out the redundant check. `if (_socketClient == null || _socketClient.IsRunning) return;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after `||` you are checking for null again, which makes the compiler "thinks" that `_socketClient` could be null when first check is false even though it is `_socketClient == null`

If it is written as follows, it does not warn about the nullability

```cs
    public async Task Connect()
    {
        if (_socketClient is null || _socketClient.IsRunning)
            return;

        await _socketClient.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, so my redundancy makes compiler forget initial check in the current context of things.